# Alternative way to get cpu informations on android

Tags: android, bash, awk, cpu, cat

I need to grab a string where it contains only the cpu name of a device
I use these methods

```
awk '/^Hardware/{print $NF}' /proc/cpuinfo 
getprop ro.product.board 
getprop ro.product.platform
```

The results are usually in this pattern

```
msmxxxx
apqxxxx
sdmxxx
kirinxxx
mtxxxx
universalxxxx
```

where x is a random number specific to the device. But sometimes all three commands return empty on some devices so any other alternative to suggest ?

Comment: When I check `/proc/cpuinfo` output I am NOT getting any string hardware there. Are you talking about `model name` here? Or else you could post the value of `/proc/cpuinfo` file off course by changing actual values with sample ones which are look alike actual values along with expected output too.

Answer (score 1):

Since I am on BASH and having `model name` in `/proc/info`'s output so giving solution as per that.

```
awk -F': +' '/model name/{print $NF}' /proc/cpuinfo
```

***Explanation:***

`-F': +'`: Setting field separator as colon space(s) all continuous occurrences for all lines here.

`/model name/`: Checking condition here if a line contains string `model name` then execute further statements.

`print $NF`: Printing `$NF` value of last column(which should be model name) from current line.

Comment: This is the same as awk '/^Hardware/{print $NF}' /proc/cpuinfo for android. I am looking for an alternative because sometimes /proc/cpuinfo doesn't include a string of CPU model

Comment: @Omar, could you please provide examples for it?